# LaTeX Error: File `substr.sty' not found

Tags: texlive, docker

I am getting following error from Latex:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `substr.sty' not found.
```

I fixed similar error by adding similar package earlier. Now, with the `substr`, the problem is that **the package could not be found any longer.**

I am sure that that package exists. Why?

- Because there are stack-overflow articles
- Documentation pages

Following command fails:

```
yum install texlive-substr* -y
```

Is not there

```
yum install texlive-* -y
```

Yes, I have executed `yum makecache -y` beforehand.

I am running docker build and I am getting following error message upon the yup install textlive-substr package:

```
Error: Unable to find a match: texlive-substr
```

Is is possible that there is some outdated packages that require this removed package?
As you see the versions are not defined for the install commands. Could that be a reason.

Comment: Note that it is highly unlikely that Linux dists provide individual latex packages a Linux packages/bundles. The `texlive-*` bundles always package up several LaTeX packages. On Ubuntu to `apt-file search substr.sty` tells be that `substr.sty is in `texlive-latex-extra` on Unbuntu.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed running it on linux cent os in docker. 
There, i am not able to find the package. 

 8.943 Error: Unable to find a match: texlive-latex-extra 

 And when it try to search for substr.sty is is not there on the docker machine. 

How could it be that something requires something that does not exist?

Comment: I don't use Cent OS, so I have no idea how to search for which Centos bundle provides which files, it should be possible to look up.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is that `texlive-substr` is in part of CentOS 8 or 9 packages.

What I ended up doing is going to https://fedora.pkgs.org/ and searching for my package.

Following worked:

```
# texlive-substr-svn16117.1.2-55.fc36.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y install  https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/t/texlive-substr-svn16117.1.2-56.el7.noarch.rpm
```

As well there were many more similar missing libs.